# Best way to build a crystal report with subreports

Tags: web-services, dataset, reporting, crystal-reports-2010

I have been tasked to create a crystal report that includes non linked subreports. It is meant to replicate the following.  I am just having a hard time wrapping my mind around where to begin.

[image]

My application consumes a webservice which returns a list of objects for each web query made. I figured that since crystal reports tends to work natively with datasets, that I would create a custom dataset containing all the tables that the queries would involve.

[image]

Now that I have created a dataset and the data is loaded from the webservice I am consuming, I have come to a point where I am attempting to figure out how to query the dataset in such a way as to join columns from each datatable and build the report from that query.

Now can someone tell me whether there is an easier way to do this or have any suggestions as to what route they might take to accomplish this?  The report needs to include subreports which complicates it a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it is cleaner and easier to maintain if you write a stored procedure in your database, and then just use that as your source in Crystal.  If you have multiple sets of data to report, use multiple stored procedures.  If you're going to have multiple subreports, it helps to have a common set of parameters for the procedures, although that is not required.

By getting your data using stored procedures, you can verify that you're getting the correct data before you write the report.  Then Crystal is used mostly for formatting and totalling.

Comment: You mean by adding a stored procedure to the webservice that I am consuming?  Because that's the only database. The client systems won't have SQL Server installed on their systems.

Comment: If possible, do your queries on the server/webservice, so that the already assembled data is what Crystal starts with.

Comment: Alright I got it doing the query on the service side now but now passing back a complex type is an issue as the type is not recognized on the client end. That will be left for another question though.  For now, your answer cleared up the initial confusion. Thank you!